# Javascript Sorting Multidimensional Array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort the multi dimensional array on a date column. The first date in each row is start date and second one is end date. I want to sort the rows in ascending order based on start date.

The datastructure is:

```
data = [["p1aprd", "Monthly", "PRD", "Date {Wed Nov 06 2013 01:27:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "Date {Thu Nov 07 2013 01:28:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "2"], 
        ["p1aprd", "Monthly", "PRD", "Date {Tue Nov 05 2013 01:29:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "Date {Wed Nov 06 2013 01:29:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "2"],
        ["p1aprd", "Monthly", "PRD", "Date {Mon Nov 04 2013 01:31:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "Date {Thu Nov 14 2013 01:31:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "2"],
        ["p1aprd", "Monthly", "PRD", "Date {Mon Nov 04 2013 01:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "Date {Thu Nov 14 2013 01:38:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}", "2"]];
```

I am trying the function:

```
data.sort((function(index){
return function(a, b){
    return (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
};})(4));

alert(data);
```

I tried all possible solutions suggested here but no luck. I might be overlooking some simple error here. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you have a 2d array there and not an array of objects?

Comment: This array is coming from some other function call and i dont have any control on that. If I have to convert that into object and reconstruct the array, is there any example which i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems with your code:
1. you are comparing date string and not date.
2. you are passing 4 whereas index of start date is 3.

Try this:

```
function getDateFromString(str){ return new Date(str.match(/\{(.*) \(/)[1]); }

data.sort((function(index){
    return function(a, b){
        a = getDateFromString(a[index]);
        b = getDateFromString(b[index]);
        return a - b;
    };
})(3));

alert(data);
```